# how would I display the value of the four variables I updated

Tags: mysql, sql

I updated some options, but dont know how to show the updates to see if they changed

```
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    SET GLOBAL max_connections = 45;
    SET GLOBAL long_query_time = 7;
    SET GLOBAL binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 3;
```

Comment: What about [reading the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html)?